# Print 4 pages per sheet without margins

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing, printer

I would like to print book in pdf format. Since book has small pages I would like to fit 4 pages per on A4 sheet. My HP Laser Jet M506 prints prints 4 pages per sheet, but leaves too broad margins:
[image]

And I would like to print with minimum margins:

[image]

I was trying to find where I can set margins, but couldn't find:

Not allowed in page setup:

[image]

Nothing about margins in `page setup` :

[image]

How to solve this problem?

I'm using PDFXchange software.

Comment: Perhaps you could do this by using software... if the book pages are in PDF format then there may be a way to use Adobe Reader to re-print the document to another PDF but change the margins... you then print the new PDF? It seems your print software doesn't provide much so you have no choice but to use software or a different printer...

Comment: Margins are set in the application, e.g. Word. Yours are set to 1". What application are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem and haven't figured out a solution. The pages are overshrunk and there seems to be no way to prescale them. Did you ever find any solution. (It's such a simple feature but of course they leave it out)